# Remove newline character in powerbuilder

Tags: character, newline, powerbuilder

How can I remove newline character from a string in powerbuilder? I have a column where I can write something and when I press enter it inserts a newline character. I want to remove it when I press save.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove the Newline character...

```
ll_pos = PosA(ls_text, "~n")

do while(ll_pos > 0)

    ls_text = ReplaceA(ls_text, ll_pos, 1, "")
    ll_pos = PosA(ls_text, "~n")

loop
```

If you need to remove the Carriage Return as well...

```
ll_pos = PosA(ls_text, "~r~n")

do while(ll_pos > 0)

    ls_text = ReplaceA(ls_text, ll_pos, 2, "")
    ll_pos = PosA(ls_text, "~r~n")

loop
```

Comment: I suggest to use Replace( ) and Pos( ) instead of ReplaceA( ) and PosA( ) since PB is using Unicode internally since PB 10.

Answer (score 0):

Another, completely different way to solve the problem is to make your `Save` button a `Default` button (third check box in the `General` tab). This way, when the user presses `Enter`, that button is actually activated.  This prevents you from further processing.  Of course, it remains to see if that behaviour is normal / desired.